# Neo4J indexing how to

Tags: graph, indexing, neo4j

I'm new to graphdb and Neo4J, so I thougt it would be a great start to buy their new graph db book, but has been very disappointed as I can't even follow along in the book.

The problem is that I don't understand the indexing, how it works and they don't even explain, like for example this code:

```
CREATE (alice {username: 'Alice'}), (bob {username: 'Bob'}), (charlie {username: 'Charlie'}),
(davina {username: 'Davina'}), (edward {username: 'Edward'}), (alice)-[:ALIAS_OF]->(bob);
```

And when I type in this:

```
START bob=node:user(username='bob'), charlie=node:user(username='Charlie'), davina=node:user(username='Davina'), edward=node:user(username='Edward')
CREATE(bob)-[:EMAILED]->(charlie), (bob)-[:CC]->(davina),(bob)-[:BCC]->(edward)
```

I get following error: ==> MissingIndexException: Index `user` does not exist

Could someone please explain to me how I index the "user".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Neo4j uses a inverted index powered by Lucene by default. So knowing it would help you understand better. I wrote a blog on this to [get you started.](http://2scompliment.wordpress.com/)

Now, the problem in your query is that you are asking neo4j to search for `bob` in index `user` under key `username`. For this to work you need to either enable [auto-indexing](http://2scompliment.wordpress.com/2013/06/22/indexing-in-neo4j/) or programatically control it.

Comment: So if I am understanding it correct and I don't programmatically control the index, then I'll have to write it like this:

`START bob=node:node_auto_index(username='bob'), charlie=node:node_auto_index(username='Charlie'), davina=node:node_auto_index(username='Davina'), edward=node:node_auto_index(username='Edward') 
CREATE(bob)-[:EMAILED]->(charlie), (bob)-[:CC]->(davina),(bob)-[:BCC]->(edward);`

and make following changes to the config:
node_auto_indexing=true
node_keys_indexable=username

Comment: @ZuhaibMian thats correct. you still need to tell neo4j to index the username property though. accept this as the answer if it helped you.

Comment: @Pangae Okay thank you, I'll give it a try and see what happens.